# RestSharp HyperCo bad request with json body

Tags: c#, json, api, request, restsharp

`

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.hyper.co/v6/licenses/");
                    var request = new RestRequest(licensekey);
                    request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
                    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer secret key");
                    RestResponse response = await client.GetAsync(request);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
                    {
                        LicenseResponse.Text = "Sucess";
                        Refresh();
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        LicenseResponse.Location = new Point(450, 330);
                        var body = "{\"hwid\":\"" + harware_id + "\"}";
                        var requestMetadata = new RestRequest($"{licensekey}/metadata");
                        requestMetadata.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
                        requestMetadata.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
                        requestMetadata.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer secret key");
                        requestMetadata.RequestFormat=DataFormat.Json;
                        requestMetadata.AddJsonBody(body) ;
                        RestResponse responseMetadata = await client.GetAsync(requestMetadata);
                        if (responseMetadata.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
                        {
                            LicenseResponse.Text = responseMetadata.ToString();
                            Refresh();
                        } else if (responseMetadata.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound) {
                            LicenseResponse.Text = responseMetadata.ToString();
                            Refresh();
                        } else if (responseMetadata.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {
                            LicenseResponse.Text = responseMetadata.ToString();
                            Refresh();
                        }
                        toolForm toolForm = new toolForm();
                        toolForm.Visible = true;
                        this.Visible= false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LicenseResponse.Text = "Error";
                        Refresh();
                        LicenseResponse.Location = new Point(438, 330);
                        Thread.Sleep(3000);
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
```

`

This is my code, when I start him got a bad request response, someone have a help tips for me ?
(you can ask me other part of the code or other th

I want to update the metadata part of hyper.co of a specific license. If it work in the dashboard of hyper.co the metadata part will change.

Comment: On which request do you get 400?
Are you specifying the secret key in the Authorization header?
`request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer secret key");` -> mayble should be secretKey from variable `request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {secretKey}");`
whats happend if you remove accept header?

Comment: metadata is a `PATCH` not `GET` so you should use `PatchAsync` not `GetAsync`

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comments, it seems to me that you are using the wrong werb to method (GET instead of PATCH), in addition you have the wrong data model
This is example for license metadata endpoint:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.hyper.co/v6/licenses/license/metadata");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.PATCH);
request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

in documentation you can generate examples for specified language (on the right)
https://docs.hyper.co/reference/update-license-metadata